# Unable to install ubuntu alongside windows 8.1 with raid0: no partitions detected

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8, uefi, raid

I tried installing Ubuntu 14.04 alongside windows 8.1 on my machine using an Ununtu USB drive in UEFI mode, but no luck:
My machine is Asus UX301, preinstalled with Windows 8, upgraded to 8.1. Got 2x128 GB HD in RAID0 (Intel Matrix). All drives are using GPT and UEFI and using Basic disk.
Problem is, after the live installer loads, it does not detect any partitions - while on Windows the partitions appear fine.
Moreoever, it shows only one 128 GB drive, so I'm assuming the problem is related to the RAID0 setup, but I do want to keep the raid setup as its very fast.

I know there are tons of similar questions, but none of what I found helped me. This is what I tried:

- Using windows, I shrunk one of the partitions, leaving 60 GB unallocated at the end of the drive.
- I disabed secureboot and fastboot
- I verified the live installer is running in UEFI mode
- I tried using GParted but it crashes on load: "Invalid argument during seek for read on /dev/sda". Then if I ignore it, it says "The backup GPT table is corrupt, but the primary appears OK, so that will be used." but when I click ok, it crashes with an assertion exception
- Running fixparts says my drive is GPT so its unsupported
- This is the output of "gdisk /dev/sda" then "v": http://pastebin.com/Y28KrMj8 (expert's 'e' didn't solve it..)
- gdisk /dev/sda then "p" does show the partitions
- dmraid -s says the raid is broken (even though it's fine on windows..)

Update:
I tried following https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FakeRaidHowto, [How to access a fake raid?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29014/how-to-access-a-fake-raid) and [configure mdadm for existing intel rapid storage array](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87979/configure-mdadm-for-existing-intel-rapid-storage-array)

1. Following the FakeRaid howto, it says it should work out of the box: "The installer will recognize the dmraid devices and allow you to use them normally. Their names will be /dev/mapper/something instead of /dev/sdX" - not working - I only have "control" under "/dev/mapper", which is obviously not a drive.
2. dmraid -s shows the following: 
   ERROR: isw: wrong number of devices in RAID set "isw_dbdcgajcci_ASUS_OS" [1/2] on /dev/sdb
   *** Group superset isw_dbdcgajcci
   --> Subset
   name   : isw_dbdcgajcci_ASUS_OS
   size   : 250065152
   stride : 256
   type   : stripe
   status : broken
   subsets: 0
   devs   : 1
   spares : 0

dmraid -r shows: "/dev/sdb: isw, "isw_dbdcgajcci", GROUP, ok, 250069678 sectors, data@ 0"

I guess I could run dmraid -R on /dev/sdb as its listed as a raid set, but I'm a little scared of rebuilding a perfectly working drive (at least under windows), unless I really know what it does and that it will help the problem I mentioned.

Comment: Your setup is commonly referred to as "fake RAID." I'm not sure if the "Intel Matrix" form of this has any specific quirks, but there are a lot of resources on this. Start with the [Fake RAID HOWTO.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FakeRaidHowto) If that doesn't help, check http://askubuntu.com/questions/87979/configure-mdadm-for-existing-intel-rapid-storage-array, http://askubuntu.com/questions/29014/how-to-access-a-fake-raid, or any of many other questions on the topic. If that fails, you'll have to post with more details, such as where things went wrong when following these guides.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 14.04.2 installer does not recognize partitions when trying to install dual-boot alongside Windows 8.1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/609107/ubuntu-14-04-2-installer-does-not-recognize-partitions-when-trying-to-install-du) and [Why is the installer not showing any partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343768/)