# Ubuntu 14.04 Installation Type screen shows no partition for Dual Boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu 14.04LTS

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, windows-10

I am having a problem doing this as the Ubuntu installer will not see any partitions except /dev/sda1 in the 3rd step when it asks for Installation Type:
[image]

EDIT from comments: In Windows 10, I shrinked current C partition used by Windows and made 40GB free for Ubuntu.

I followed number of articles and changed settings on Windows to disable Secure Boot and enable Legacy boot and that allowed me to boot from bootable USB with Ubuntu 14.04 on it.

Once I boot from USB, I get the menu to Test Ubuntu or Install it. I click on Test and that opens Ubuntu from where I can click on desktop M icon "Install Ubuntu". But that takes me only up to this step.

I have tried same with Ubuntu 15.10 (both are 64 bits as recommended for Windows 10).

Once in Test Ubuntu, here is what gdisk returns. Not sure if that can help though:

[image]

Comment: Have you considered resizing the partition with gparted? gdisk  is reporting that sda1 ends at sector 30949375  and the last usable sector is 30949342, hence the warning regarding an overlap of 33.

Comment: A free partition is created on Widows 10 side as per numerous articles I found online for installing dual boot Win10/Ubuntu.  In Windows 10, I shrinked current C partition used by Windows and made 40GB free for Ubuntu.  I am not sure why gdisk is reporting that though, it is strange.  I havent use gparted, did it from Windows 10.  Here is the link I used (among number of others) http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2015/11/how-to-install-ubuntu-linux-alongside.html  Thanks

Comment: After spending over 3 decades supporting Windows I've learned to take Windows with a grain of salt. Would you be so kind as to [edit] your question and include a link to a screenshot of gparted showing the drive in question? Thank you.

Comment: Did you reinstall Windows in BIOS mode on a system that was UEFI? Windows only boots in BIOS mode from MBR(msdos) partitioned drives. And only in UEFI mode from gpt drives. But Windows does not correctly convert from gpt to MBR. So you have left over gpt data that confuses most Linux partition tools. You must remove gpt data or reinstall Windows in UEFI boot mode. You can use fixparts to remove gpt data. http://www.rodsbooks.com/fixparts/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 14.04.2 installer does not recognize partitions when trying to install dual-boot alongside Windows 8.1](https://askubuntu.com/q/609107/) and [Why is the installer not showing any partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/q/343768/)

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should do is install windows 10. From there Using disk management you spit a portion of your harddrive and leave it as free space. Then with you efi bootable usb you run the linux install process. Make sure that the installer has launched in efi mode and not bios mode. To do this on the installation you can type [ -d /sys/firmware/efi ] && echo UEFI || echo BIOS
If it launched in UEFI after you hit installation you should get the option to install Ubuntu alongside window.

So important things:

1. Install Windows 10 first.
2. Have a usb UEFI bootable with linux(I use rufus to make mine.)
3. Using a partition tool, shrink your volume(I have 25gb for my linux.)
4. Launch Linux and make you it booted in UEFI mode using [ -d /sys/firmware/efi ] && echo UEFI || echo BIOS
5. An option to install Ubuntu alongside windows should be present, just install.

Comment: I have Windows 10 installed.  I split (shrinked) partition and made 40GB free for Ubuntu on Windows side (as per https://www.enswe.com/tutorial/dual-boot-ubuntu-fedora-windows-10), then I downloaded Ubuntu USB using Universal USB installer which number of articles recommend(https://www.enswe.com/tutorial/dual-boot-ubuntu-fedora-windows-10).  Once I reboot from USB, I get option to Try Ubuntu and Install it.  I tried both, either way, I see no partitions.  Thanks,

Comment: @dbnex14 In future please [edit] additional relevant  info into your question. Not everyone will read all the comments and comments can be deleted for a number of reasons.

Comment: @dbnex14 I want you to run the live mode of linux and go into terminal. type in step 4 and reply if it returns Bios or UEFI

Answer (score 0):

@dbnex14... Hi I had a similar problem and I managed to fix it using [FixParts](http://www.rodsbooks.com/fixparts/)... The are some good instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343768/why-is-it-not-showing-any-partitions/) on how to proceed.
Hope it can help you out!