# Partitions not detected during installation Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, 17.10, usb-installation, boot-partition

I deleted the Ubuntu 64bit partition from Windows 10 to extend its size and I am trying to reinstall it on my PC. The problem is, Ubuntu installer is neither detecting the windows installation nor the partitions I've made on my hard disk using windows. The installer shows an empty hard disk (no partitions) where I can install Ubuntu. I'm afraid if I continue to install I might break the existing partitions and lose my files. But the partition manager "Gparted" is showing all the existing partitions correctly. Only the installer is not able to detect the partitions.

I made a bootable USB drive for Ubuntu installation using "Universal USB Installer".

Here is the output of sudo parted /dev/sda print and sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo parted /dev/sda
GNU Parted 3.2
Using /dev/sda
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) 

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/loop0: 1.5 GiB, 1553670144 bytes, 3034512 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xe849da94

Device     Boot      Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *          2048     718847     716800   350M  7 HPFS/NTFS/e
/dev/sda2           718848  315125759  314406912 149.9G  7 HPFS/NTFS/e
/dev/sda3        315125760  827127807  512002048 244.1G  7 HPFS/NTFS/e
/dev/sda4        827127745 1953519615 1126391871 537.1G  f W95 Ext'd (
/dev/sda5        827127808 1246851071  419723264 200.1G  7 HPFS/NTFS/e
/dev/sda6       1246853120 1339127807   92274688    44G 83 Linux
/dev/sda7       1339129856 1953519615  614389760   293G  7 HPFS/NTFS/e

Partition 4 does not start on physical sector boundary.




Disk /dev/sdb: 3.8 GiB, 4051697664 bytes, 7913472 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Device     Boot Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *      128 7913471 7913344  3.8G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

I cannot boot to Windows nor install Ubuntu since the partitions aren't detected. Should I convert MBR partitions to GPT so they are detected during the installation? Is it doable without losing my data?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is the installer not showing any partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343768/why-is-the-installer-not-showing-any-partitions) and [Ubuntu 14.04.2 installer does not recognize partitions when trying to install dual-boot alongside Windows 8.1.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/609107/)

Answer (score 0):

Quick search at given problem shows that either partition table is faulty or some other issue. Look at [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343768/why-is-it-not-showing-any-partitions) before going into solution.

My understandings is that I am suspecting something odd about mismatching bootable media and UEFI. I know from experience that Universal USB Installer does not prepare a USB stick for booting against UEFI (It supports old BIOS) because I had a similar issue very ago in past. Windows 10 told me that system is in UEFI mode so I had to change boot mode on USB. I recommend you the same as first attempt. I also recommend using "Rufus" tool on any Windows machine and prepare "Ubuntu" against UEFI option under **Rufus** *see image especially options 1 & 2 for help*.

Otherwise, to correct the problem if partition table is involved, you may have to format the drive which is tedious.

[image: Rufus - options 1 & 2]